# Ajustar programaticamente el tamaño de ventana Cocoa

Tags: swift

Estoy intentando que el tamaño de una ventana que contiene una vista se ajuste al tamaño de esta. He intentado esto, en el controlador de la escena (ViewController):

```
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        
        // Ajusta el tamaño de la vista (A4)
        self.vista.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 842, height: 595)
        
        // Obtiene la ventana
        if let ventana = self.vista.window {
            let marco = NSRect(
                x: 50,
                y: 50,
                width: self.vista.frame.width + 17,
                height: self.vista.frame.height + 47
            )
            ventana.setFrame(marco, display: true)
            ventana.title = "Circuito"
            
            print(ventana.frame)
        }
```

Pero la ventana siempre tiene el tamaño que tenía la ultima vez que se ejecutó el programa.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Quieres que un componente `View` se ajuste al tamaño de la pantalla? Intentaste desde el `storyboard` agregar los constraints?

Comment: El problema es que la vista está dentro de un Scroll View que se puede ajustar al tamaño de la ventana, pero no conozco la forma de ajustar la ventana con storyboard. No conozco la forma de hacer constraints de una vista o ventana con respecto a una de sus subvistas.

Answer (score -1):

Resuelto!

Si se coloca el código para ajustar el tamaño de la ventana en el método viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    // Ajusta el tamaño de la vista (A4)
    self.vista.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 842, height: 595)
        
    // Obtiene la ventana
    if let ventana = self.vista.window {
        let marco = NSRect(
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            width: self.vista.frame.width + 17,
            height: self.vista.frame.height + 87
        )
        ventana.setFrame(marco, display: true)
}
```

La ventana no se redimensiona. Pero si se coloca en otro método:

```
func ajusta() {
    // Ajusta el tamaño de la vista (A4)
    self.vista.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 842, height: 595)
        
    // Obtiene la ventana
    if let ventana = self.vista.window {
        let marco = NSRect(
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            width: self.vista.frame.width + 17,
            height: self.vista.frame.height + 87
        )
        ventana.setFrame(marco, display: true)
    }
}
```

Y en viewDidApear se llama a ese método:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
        
    self.ajusta()
}
```

Si que se redimensiona la ventana.

Lo que no sé es por qué.

Saludos de Víctor.-

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).